# svn commit issue with NetBeans

Tags: svn, netbeans-7, rapidsvn

My svn client is rapidsvn and ide is NetBeans. I suddenly got an error when I am going to commit my updates. I have given 777 permission and change owner of project, but still I couldn't fix that issue.

When I commit the file in NetBeans it gives below error:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
E175002: Broken pipe
E175002: PROPFIND request failed on '/team/proporta3/branches/3.1.2/application/views/layouts'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue after upgrading NetBeans from 7.2 to 7.2.1. I had to **Tools** / **Options** / **Miscellaneous** / **Versioning**. Than choose Subversion and **CLI** under '**Preferred client**'. 
After that I was able to svn as usual.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone. Finally I got the issue. I have set and apply a local proxy for system wide (for Jmeter performance testing). After stop that is working well.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was a proxy issue , I restarted again after disabling the proxy and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've posted some steps you can check here: [Netbeans RapidSVN and respositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431304/netbeans-rapidsvn-and-respositories/14446718#14446718).

Please try an alternate client too - maybe it's a problem of rapidsvn.