# Netbeans RapidSVN and respositories

Tags: svn, netbeans, version-control, rapidsvn

I had a Netbeans project with all the directory structure and so forth. I imported my Netbeans project to an online repository. The above was all done with a windows pc.

Now, with Ubuntu and RapidSVN (a GUI svn client) I checked out my repository to the NetBeansProjects Directory.

When I load NetBeans I get a class not found exception saying:

```
A java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception has occurred.
However, the system should continue working without further problems.
Click Show Details for the stack trace.
```

Here are the details:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tigris.subversion.javahl.SVNClientInterface
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
        ...
        ...
```

So, I now can look at all my files and edit them. However, whenever I make changes and then test and run my program it appears to always run the version that was loaded to the repository.

In the same vein, it appears that it does not save any of my changes. When I close and open Netbeans the project that I was just editing from the repository does not appear in the projects panel off to the left.

1. How can I get Netbeans to keep this as a project and save the changes?
2. Am I using RapidSVN wrong?
3. Am I using my repository wrong?

Let me know if you have any other suggestions or need any more details.

Answer (score 1):

What Version of NetBeans and RapidSvn do you use? What version of Subversion is running on the server?
NetBeans 7 supports SVN 1.7, while RapidSVN isn't up to date.

After you have made changes do a *commit* so the current files get uploaded into the SVN.

Here are some things you can try:

- Checkout your with NetBeans (**`Team -> Subversion -> Checkout`**)
- Make a *commit* using NB, if this doesn't work make an *upddate* (NB too)
- Do you have rights to write the directory? Any difference if you ran RapidSVN as *sudo*?
- Check these settings in NB: **`Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Versioning -> Subversion`**: *Preffered Client* (What do you have here? If not set yet: try with *SvnKit*)

If all fails, have a look at following (free) alternate clients:

- [SmartSVN](http://www.smartsvn.com/) (Linux / Win)
- [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) (Win only)
- [eSvn](http://zoneit.free.fr/esvn/) (Linux / Win)

See: [NetBeans FAQ - SVN Client](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSubversionClients)